# How to display the 3collections data in one table in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 collections and one object
#

```
scope.quessionary={};
$scope.jobquestions=[{"id": 2,
                      "category": "raju",
                       "question": "haii?",}];
$scope.companyquestionsquestions=[{"id": 2,
                      "category": "ramu",
                       "question": "hello?",}];
$scope.departmentquestions=[{"id": 2,
                      "category": "somu",
                       "question": "hello?",}];
```

Now i have to display the category and question field values inthe  all collections in  one table how can i display ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.quessionary = [];
$scope.quessionary = $scope.quessionary.concat($scope.jobquestions).concat($scope.companyquestionsquestions).concat($scope.departmentquestions);
```

And in the html:

```
<table>
    ....
    <tr ng-repeat="question in quessionary">
        <td>{{question.category}}</td>
        <td>{{question.question}}</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```